# SQL Calculated Table that Only Recalculates when Underlying Data Changes

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two massive tables that change (get rows added and removed) from time to time: **Table 1** and **Table 2**

I also have a complex query - **Query 1** that returns a table from a complex function of **Table 1** and **Table 2**

**Query 1** takes very long to run because the underlying tables are large and it is a complex query. Is there a type of Structure in SQL (View, table function, not sure what it is... ) which will save the results of the complex query - **Query 1** and return it instantly if underlying tables - **Table 1** and **Table 2** have not changed but will otherwise recalculate and return the result if they have changed?

Comment: An indexed view, if the "complex query" does not use [constructs disallowed in this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/views/create-indexed-views?view=sql-server-ver15#additional-requirements). This maintains the resultset along with every change to the base tables not on demand by a reader

Comment: @MartinSmith in the "complex query" there are disallowed constructs... do I have any other option?

Comment: Nothing built in, you would need to code something yourself that either keeps a materialized resultset updated with triggers or just refreshes it as a batch if the underlying tables have been written to